# What is a matrix with no Jordan canonical form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Could somebody give me an example of a matrix that doesn’t admit a Jordan Canonical Form over $\mathbb R$ and explain why it does not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A matrix admits a Jordan canonical form just when all its eigenvalues lie in the base field. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

So all you need is a matrix with at least one nonreal eigenvalue. Write down the matrix for a quarter circle rotation in the plane.

Comment: With at least one non-real eigenvalue?

Comment: @Loobear23 Fixed thanks. You could have edited to do that.